# Why is file downloaded using ImageIO smaller than browser downloaded file?

Tags: java, image, download, image-size

The code below downloads an image from the specified URL.
When the same image is saved locally from the browser, it is significantly larger than the one downloaded programmatically by about a factor of 66%.

Although the code does not explicitly specify any parameters about the size, why is the downloaded file smaller than the one downloaded from the browser?

```
BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("random url to an image"));
ImageIO.write(buffImage, "jpg", new File("MyAppDl.jpg"));
```

EDIT: Weird ... it isn't consistent; on a different URL the thumbnail is distinctly smaller

Comment: Which of the two files is corrupted?

Comment: Look at file contents and tell us the difference.

Comment: An example image URL that reproduces the problem would be helpful

Comment: Neither is corrupt, the content appears to be identical prima-facie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess: the brower loads the file "as is" ... your code reads the file into a data structure and then writes it again to a file. Most probably it appls default compression that might be higher then the orginal used ratio.

If you want the original file do not use `BufferedImage` and `ImageIO` but read/write it with plain streams.

Answer (score 2):

The `ImageIO` version is being uncompressed and re-compressed with a different quality setting. Don't do this, use the regular `Stream` classses that don't manipulate the data and just pass it through un-interpreted.